# Is there a way to launch a custom application in android whenever any camera application captures an image

Tags: android, camera, android-camera-intent

Let me clarify this first, this isn't anything similar to asking whether or not I can make my own camera application to capture and process an image however I want.
What I want is to devise an application which gets launched in background whenever an image is capture by my android phone's camera (using any application, factory or otherwise), so that I can process that image and save it anyway I want.

Is it possible without diving into the root level programming?

Answer (score -1):

Probably it can be implemented with the careful use `Broadcast Receivers` for the event of image capture by camera. Though i haven't implemented this before but it seems reasonable to work. It involves three following steps --

**1. Creation of Broadcast Receiver**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MyReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "image captured by camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**2. Registering Receiver in manifest file**

Under `<application>` tag in manifest file put this intent receiver. `action` here defines on what actions you want your receiver to be activated/ listen. For camera button event `action` is `android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON`.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
             </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**3. Registering the receiver in your activity**

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(getPackageName() + "android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON");

MyReceiver myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
```

To unregister a receiver in onStop() or onPause() of the activity the following can be used --

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

I am hoping this should work fine. If not, let me know what problem you are facing.

Comment: That's an intent to start a media capture.  It isn't a broadcast sent when a picture is taken.

Comment: I'm not absolutely certain, but I think that refers to a hardware camera button only.  But I don't have the time tonight to check.